# Add font from Google Fonts on WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add the Open Sans font from Google Fonts. I tried to add a `<link>` in my `<head>` by editing `header.php`, but nothing changed.

My browser (Firefox) doesn't load the Open Sans font and falls back to a generic sans-serif font, which is wider and causes the text to break into multiple lines.

I'm using Wordpress 4.9 with the WpResidence theme and the Visual Composer plugin.

Comment: Is there any required plugins with this theme?

Comment: @ShantunParmar no

Comment: You may try with customise theme, when you go to menu you can add custom html in which you can provide a link

Comment: @ShantunParmar i already tried to add the link to the header.php but nothing changes

Comment: can you share your website link?

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. It is really hard to help you, when all you give us are such absolutely vague problem descriptions.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming the actual question is: “How to add a font from Google Fonts?” and this is a case of the [X-Y Problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Let me know if this is not the case.

---

To add a font from Google Fonts:

- You could [create a child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/), copy the `header.php` file from your parent theme to your child theme and add the `<link>` tag for your font.
- You could [create a child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) and load the font with `@import` in your `style.css`.
- You could [create a child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) or [create a plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/), and enqueue the font like this:

  ```php
  <?php
  function add_google_font() { 
      wp_enqueue_style( 'open-sans-font', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' ); 
  }

  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_google_font' );
  ```